# Resize SVG to left/right/top/bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I want to resize a `svg` after it was created and inserted into the `DOM`.
I use these two lines

```
var newHeight = ($("#someSvg").height() + 20).toString();
$("#someSvg").css("height", newHeight);
```

The additional Pixels are getting added to the right side of the `svg`. 
Is there a way to tell "add equaly x Pixel to both sides (left/right) of the `svg`" or "add x Pixel to the left, y Pixel to the right?" Same for the height...

Comment: as far as I know it's not possible. you could achieve what you want using the css "scale" property.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use some CSS margins?

Comment: @jcaron I want to draw something in that svg. The stuff I draw are circles. When they are located at the border of the svg, only half the circle will be displayed. Would amrgin solve that?

Comment: Sorry, had misunderstood your issue. Want you want is extend the SVG whenever something is drawn near the edge? You could adjust the `viewBox`, where the `x` and `y` can become negative if you want to extend to the top or left.

Comment: @jcaron It does not really depend on when something gets drawn or not. I only want to extend it, after its creation

Comment: The answer still stands. Just adjust the viewBox. If you want to extend to the left by 20, add 20 to the width and subtract 20 from x. An alternative would be to add a transform on a group that would contain everything inside the SVG. Or simply move all elements inside the SVG, though that can quickly become complex depending on the type of primitives you use.

Comment: @jcaron okay. thanks! I have a transform/translate on the svg already so that might make thinks even more complex